# input tag proportional size to td tag

Tags: input, html-table

How can I have my input tag the same syze as  the td tag
see this example. Important, all the td tag width are set with percentage (%). the % is stated in the th tag in a separate css file.

```
<table id="wrec_1">
    <tr>
        <th class="clsCellLoc">Cell
            <br />Loc.</th>
        <th class="clsChannel">Chanel
            <br />(color)</th>
        <th class="clsReset">Reset
            <br />zeros
            <br />y</th>
        <th class="clsReading">Reading
            <br />A1
            <br />(lb)</th>
        <th class="clsZero">Zero scale
            <br />Reading (B1)
            <br />(lb)</th>
        <th class="clsActual">Actual Weight
            <br />C1= A1–B1
            <br />(lb)</th>
        <th class="clsComment" rowspan="5">Comments:
            <br />
            <textarea id="wercComments" name="S1" wrap="hard"></textarea>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="">Nose</td>
        <td class="">
            <input type=text />
        </td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class="" id="_1NoseActualWeight">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/le_beluet/8tV6B/)!

Comment: Hi, if you go an see the link link you will see the input box larger than it should be. I want that input box to fit in the td tag after the <td class="">Nose</td>